# How to add max_result_window in elastic search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

My Query is below which works fine. My query is very big to show so i am putting sample query below

`es.search(index="data", body={'query': {'match' : {'professor.contactName': 'Steve'}}})`

I need to add 'max_result_window':1000, to my body query

`es.search(index="data", body={'max_result_window':1000, 'query': {'match' : {'proffessor.contactName': 'Steve'}}})`

I am getting "RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [max_result_window].')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer this [put_settings](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_settings)

I think u need to use put_settings method. Try below one.

```
es.indices.put_settings(index='data', 
                        body={'index' : 
                             {'max_result_window':1000}})
```

Comment: RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'unknown setting [index.query.match.proffessor.contactName] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings')

Comment: Discard match query json :  {'match' : {}}

Comment: yeah its working so if we want to write some query how to do?

Comment: please change the answer . First need to update the `max_result_window`  through es.indices.put_settings then do es.search

Comment: `es.indices.put_settings(index='data',   body={'index' : {'max_result_window':1000}})`

Comment: Yes, now you can use simple search query after setting max_result_window.

Answer (score 1):

This is a index level setting and you can change it by updating the index setting, for which you need to close the index, hit endpoint `http://<es-host>:9200/<index-name>/_settings` with below payload and PUT method and again open the index.

```
{
  "index.max_result_window": 1000
}
```

But this way to updating the max_result_window is not recommended and there are better options such as `scroll` and `search_after` available as mentioned in [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html)

Comment: How to add scroll and search_after in the python query?  es.search(index="data", body={'query': {'match' : {'professor.contactName': 'Steve'}}})

Comment: search_after you mean to say `size:10000` which i tried and not working

Comment: @Nons please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after for more info, I am not aware of python :( sorry but ES is JSON based, so you should be able to make it work in JSON format and I see you are crossing even 10k which is safegaurd placed by ES

Comment: @Nons in this case, as suggested in official doc of search_after, you should use a scroll API

Comment: can u check once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260453/how-to-sort-with-case-insensitive. I need to change without change in the settings