# How to sort with case insensitive without changing the settings

Tags: elasticsearch

My index name is data_new

Below is the code to insert into index

```
test = [   {'id':1,'name': 'A', 'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    { 'id':2,  'name': 'AB', 'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']},
    {'id':3,   'name': 'a',   'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    {'id':4,'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':5,'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':6,'name': 'Theatre 410', 'professor': ['Sebastian Hern', 'art']},
    {'id':7,'name': 'Accounting 101', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':8,'name': 'Marketing 101', 'professor': ['William Smith', 'finance']},
    {'id':8,'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'professor': ['Devin Cranford', 'history']},
    {'id':10,   'name': 'Computer Science 101',
        'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']}]
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='data_new', ignore=400)
for e in test:
        es.index(index="data_new", body=e, id=e['id'])
search = es.search(index="data_new", body={"from" : 0, "size" : 2,"query": {"match_all": {}}})
search['hits']['hits']
```

Right now

```
[{'id':1,'name': 'A'},
{ 'id':2,  'name': 'AB'},
{'id':3,   'name': 'a'}]
```

Expected is in below order

```
[{'id':1,'name': 'A'},
{ 'id':3,  'name': 'a'},
{'id':2,   'name': 'AB'}]
```

for input `["a", "b",  "B", "C", "c", "A"]` 
the result is :  `["A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c"]`

I want output as `["A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c"]`

Expected out

My first Expected output > I need to sort the output with respect to name only in {Case insensitive}. I need to normalise name keyword and sort

How to do the modification on `search = es.search(index="data_new", body={"from" : 0, "size" : 2,"query": {"match_all": {}}})`

I have updated the code with below
`search = es.search(index="data_new", body={ "sort" : [{"name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}], {"size": 1000, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "A"}}})`

with `"normalizer": "case_insensitive"}`
I got the error

`RequestError: RequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:41] [field_sort] unknown field [normalizer]')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fields not getting sorted in alphabetical order in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382734/fields-not-getting-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas  case insensitive without changing the settings

Comment: http://www.technocratsid.com/sort-strings-alphabetically-rather-than-lexicographically-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: you cant without changing setting

Comment: @hamidbayat  i tried with setting mentioned in the link but could not help  `search = es.search(index="data_new", body={ "sort" : [{"name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}}], "from":0, "size":100, "query":{ "match_all":{}}}) search['hits']['hits'] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use normalizer, you need to define it into your mapping. you are not able to use it as an argument in your search. In your case, you need to have two fields for sort. I have made this by copying data to other fields. the first field has lowercase normalizer and the other one not.

```
PUT /test_index/
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "myLowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "post":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "normalizer":"myLowercase",
              "type":"keyword",
              "copy_to": [
              "name2"
            ]
           },
           "name2":{
              "type":"keyword"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

And your query would be something like this:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },"sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "name2":{
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the mapping and setting that you must have for your *name* field in your indices and you need to add other fields to the mapping as well. Please have the attention that this is for elasticsearch version below 7. If you use elasticsearch version 7 you must delete doc_type which is named *post* here from the mapping.

Comment: Is there any way to change without touch the settings

Comment: { "sort" : [{"name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}}], "from":0, "size":2, "query":{ "match_all":{}}}), how to apply normalizer without change the settings

Comment: I don't see a way and I think this can not happen. Because Normalizer is something that must be executed in the indexing section, not in the selection part.

Comment: is there any way to do this? in selection part

Comment: I don't see a way for doing this. You can see how to use normalizer in elasticsearch in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html).

Comment: I am not getting in order

Comment: search = es.search(index="data_new", body={
  "sort" : [{"name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}}],
 "from":0, "size":100, "query":{ "match_all":{}}})
search['hits']['hits']

Comment: I tried with raw also `search = es.search(index="data_new", body={
  "sort" : [{"name.raw" : {"order" : "asc"}}],
 "from":0, "size":100, "query":{ "match_all":{}}})
search['hits']['hits']`

Comment: I tried the settings told in http://www.technocratsid.com/sort-strings-alphabetically-rather-than-lexicographically-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: You mean you have created a new index with configs of the link that you sent?

Comment: yes, i tried with your settings and also i  followed the link i mentioned, but its not sorting. A,a,AB

Comment: `settings = { "settings": { "analysis": { "normalizer": { "myLowercase": { "type": "custom", "filter": [ "lowercase" ] } } } }, "mappings":{ "post":{ "properties":{ "name":{ "normalizer":"myLowercase", "type":"keyword" } } } } }`

Comment: Is this a valid response for you ["A","a","AB", "B", "b"] ?

Comment: So, I edited my response to you. You need to have two fields for sort. I made it. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, Did you try this? was that something that you needed?

Comment: i will check and let you know, between what is `name2`

Comment: That's OK. name2 is a extra field which is automatically filled by elasticsearch (set copy_to in mapping) and help you to have sort in that way you want. By sorting on two field you will have sort somehow you want.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this you will have to use a script with `ctx._source.mykey.toLowerCase()`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html

You can find another post which talk about it:
[Script-based sorting on Elasticsearch date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933085/script-based-sorting-on-elasticsearch-date-field)
And a good article with an example here:
https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-painless-scripting-in-elasticsearch

Code will look like (not tested)

```
{
 "query": {
   "match_all": {}
 },
 "sort": {
   "_script": {
     "type": "string",
     "order": "asc",
     "script": {
       "lang": "painless",
       "inline": "doc['name.keyword'].value.toLowerCase()"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Note: It's a bad practice and you should do it only for a one shot query. If you want your application to stay healthy you should implement the solution suggested by saeednasehi.
You can also use index sorting to be more performant.